# How to process a form that consists of nested component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I created a dynamically changing form, using my own components and I am not sure how can I get the information out of it since the select tag itself exists only in the children components. 
I googled and found that I need to use refs, though I am not sure how to do it either. Another option I found is to use 
`document.getElementsByClassName`, but for some reasons, it's not an optimal way to do it, apparently.

[the parent class where the form exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pr1VF.png)

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ChoicePair from'./ChoicePair';
import ChoosingPane from './ChoosingPane';

class AppComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    numChildren: 3
  }

  render () {
    const children = [];
    this.subjects = [ {name: 'a', dep: 1}, {name: 'b', dep: 2}, {name: 'c', dep: 1}, {name: 'd', dep: 1}];

    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.numChildren; i ++) {
      children.push(<ChoicePair key={i} number={i} options = {this.subjects} subjects = {this.subjects}/>);
    };

    return (
      <div>
       <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <ChoosingPane addChild={this.onAddChild}>
          {children}
        </ChoosingPane>
        <button type = "submit"> Get my perfect schedule </button>
      </form>
{      console.log(document.getElementById("kira") + "WOW")
}
      </div>
    );
  }

  onAddChild = () => {
    this.setState({
      numChildren: this.state.numChildren + 1
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("hi!");
}

}



export default AppComponent;
```

The mid component

```
import React from 'react';

const ChoosingPane = props => (
  <div>
  <div id="children-pane">
    {props.children}
  </div>
  <div className="card calculator">
    <p><button onClick={props.addChild}>+</button></p>
  </div>
  </div>
);

export default ChoosingPane;
```

[the leaf class where the select tag exists (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghFmA.png)

import React, {Component} from 'react';

```
class ChoicePair extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super();
    console.log("KKKKKKK");
    this.state = {
      depValue: '-1',
      subValue: '-1',
  }

    this.handleDepChange = this.handleDepChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubChange = this.handleSubChange.bind(this);

    this.getNames = this.getNames.bind(this);

  }

  handleDepChange(event) {
    this.setState({depValue: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubChange(event) {
    this.setState({subValue: event.target.value});
  }

  getNames(collection)
  {
    console.log(collection);
    if(collection)
    return collection.map( (item, i) => {
      return <option id="kira" key = {i} value={i} cat = {item}>{item.name}</option>
    });

  }
  render() {
  //create filtered options constant


  const subjectList = this.props.subjects.filter((subjName) => subjName.dep === Number(this.state.depValue));


  console.log(subjectList + "kill me");

  return(
    <div>
      <select name = "Select department"  value={this.state.depValue} onChange = {this.handleDepChange}>
        <option value = '-1' disabled>Department</option>
        {this.getNames(this.props.options)}
      </select>

      <select name = "Select subject"  value={this.state.subValue} onChange = {this.handleSubChange}>
        <option value = '-1' disabled>Subject</option>
        {this.getNames(subjectList)}
      </select>

    </div>
  )

  }

}

export default ChoicePair;
```

[the leaf class where the select tag exists (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vGRI.png)

Comment: Please share real code that users here can copy and manipulate, not pictures of code.

Comment: Please post your code here.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, getElementsByClassNames works, but you can also use references on Dom nodes, or you can look into your architecture and use callback functions. 
This is a good link if you are just starting to work with react and need some basic guidance with forms